# Python : How to create multiple functions work repeatedly and each function work different number of times?

Tags: python, function

i am making a 'take a break reminder' for water,eyes,exercise. The problem is the functions wont repeat if i use break and if i use continue they work infinitely. I want each function to work different number of times .
WORKING OF MY PROGRAM:
user will input to start the program
it will remind him to drink water,eye exercise,physical exercise each after 28 min , 30 min, 48 mins and x,y,z number o times

```
#import modules
import pygame #for playing reminder music
import time


# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
# water reminder
def water():
    totalbreaks2 = 2
    breakcount2 = 0
    while breakcount2 < totalbreaks2:

        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load("water.mp3.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        query = input('Did you drink water (type drank if yes)?')
        if query == 'drank':
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            time.sleep(1)
            breakcount2+=1
        break


# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
# eye exercise reminder
def eyes():
    totalbreaks = 2
    breakcount = 0
    while breakcount < totalbreaks:
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load("eyes.mp3.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        query = input('Did you do eyes exercise ?(type eydone if yes)')
        if query == 'eydone':
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            time.sleep(1)
            breakcount += 1
            break


# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
# physical exercise reminder
def exercise():
    totalbreaks1 = 2
    breakcount1 = 0
    while breakcount1 < totalbreaks1:
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load("physical.mp3.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        query = input('Did you do physical exercise (type exdone if yes) ?:')
        if query == 'exdone':
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            time.sleep(1)
            breakcount1+=1


z = input('Do you want to start the program? (y=yes , n=no):')
if z == 'y':
    water()
    eyes()
    exercise()
elif z == 'n':
    print('ok')
else:
    print('type correct input')
```

Comment: To do this following your current design, you'll have to introduce concurrency, e.g. through threads or an asynchronicity framework like [`trio`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) or [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). An alternative would be to calculate the next reminders in a single loop.

Comment: can you elaborate I am a beginner

Comment: Stack Overflow is not design or tutorial site; asking is to teach you how to implement multiprocessing is *far* out of scope of what this site does.  Unfortunately, this is not a beginner topic -- you need to train yourself past the beginner point to do what you want.  You could also do it by restructuring your program to run on a single loop with several independent timing/event counters -- look up how to do simple event-driven projects, and you can get somewhere.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  This will remind you how we work, and what we expect in a posting.  The code you gave us is loaded with statements irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of three loops, you could use one:

```
import time
import pygame

# settings
things = {
    "water": {
        "times": 2,
        "every": 28,
    },
    "eye": {
        "times": 2,
        "every": 30,
    },
    "physical": {
        "times": 2,
        "every": 48,
    },
}

# initial scheduling
schedule = []
for thing, data in things.items():
    if data["times"] < 1:
        continue
    data["times"] -= 1
    schedule.append((data["every"], thing))
schedule.sort()

# main loop; while we have things to do
while schedule:
    delay, thing = schedule.pop(0)
    print("Next thing:", thing, "in", delay, "minutes")
    time.sleep(delay * 60)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(f"{thing}.mp3.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    did = input(f"Did you do {thing}? Type yes if done> ") == "yes"
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    schedule = list((other_delay - delay, other) for (other_delay, other) in schedule)
    if not did:
        schedule.append((things[thing]["every"], thing))
    elif things[thing]["times"] >= 1:
        things[thing]["times"] -= 1
        schedule.append((things[thing]["every"], thing))
    schedule.sort()
```

The idea here is to keep a sorted list of currently scheduled reminders. When we slept enough for the earliest one, we reduce the delay in the other ones by the amount we slept, e.g.:

---

We schedule `[(28, "water"), (30, "eye"), (48, "physical")]`. After waiting for 28 minutes and reminding the user of water, we subtract `28` from both remaining elements: `[(2, "eye"), (18, "physical")]`. If we didn't do the task, or if there are instances of this task remaining (tracked through the `"times"` key) we also reschedule the original task (`"water"`) with the original delay (28 minutes).